# Itunes app store reject Smartface 4.5

Tags: smartface.io

I upload ios appstore app which is working with backend server getting info by Webclient and appstore rejected my app due to connection problem to backend serevrer as:

> Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required.

Does any one knows about IpV6 compatibility of SMF 4.5?
Does any one meet problem after 1 June 2016 for IOS?

Comment: I think that you should contact Smartface Team directly. Probably they will know the answer.